# shutting down computer suite with option to stop (.bat file loaded onto server)

Tags: batch-file, server, shutdown, system-shutdown

I am trying to figure out how to create a batch file which is loaded on to a server and can shut off 52 desktops at a particular time. 
I understand that this is to be run for each computer:

```
shutdown –m \\computername01 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60 
shutdown –m \\computername02 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60
```

etc...

The thing is though, I want to be able to provide the option to cancel the shutdown in case someone is still using the computer at the time the task is scheduled.

Would something like this work:

```
@echo off
echo Your PC will shutdown in 30 seconds! Press CTRL+C to abort.
ping -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
shutdown –m \\computername01 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60 
shutdown –m \\computername02 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60
```

or would it have to be something like:

```
@echo off
echo Your PC will shutdown in 30 seconds! Press CTRL+C to abort.
ping -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
shutdown –m \\computername01 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60 
@echo off
echo Your PC will shutdown in 30 seconds! Press CTRL+C to abort.
ping -n 31 127.0.0.1>nul
shutdown –m \\computername02 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60
```

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CHOICE` to wait for a keypress, then run `shutdown /a`.

Like this:

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO Your computer will shutdown in 60 seconds, press C to abort.
SHUTDOWN –m \\computername01 –s –f –c “The computer will restart, please save all work.” –t 60
CHOICE -c c -n -t 70 -d c
SHUTDOWN -a
```

This would start the shutdown timer, wait for the user to press C, and then cancel the shutdown. (Also, the `CHOICE` will wait 70 seconds, while the countdown - 60 seconds.)